# Python Requests Library - Chunked Data & iter_lines

Tags: python, python-requests

Anyone here experienced with Requests and HTTP streaming with Chunked Data encoding.

I'm wondering if Requests inherently knows the chunk size provided by the server, and uses it in requests.iter_lines() as the chunk size.  I'm finding if i reduce the default chunk size, it processes faster, but is there any correlation to what the server sends back and i shouldn't be monkeying around with setting it.  Note, i'm eating social data feeds from DataSift in real time and ultimately shooting them to standard out.

code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import json


headers={'Auth': 'username:api_key'}
r = requests.get('http://stream.datasift.com/988098098sd09fsd89fsd0f7',headers=headers, stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines(chunk_size=128):
    if line: 
        print line
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source code (models.py line [531](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/c4f9340fb4df41d7a8be66ee41c40bfed64ec6d6/requests/models.py#L531) and [31](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/c4f9340fb4df41d7a8be66ee41c40bfed64ec6d6/requests/models.py#L31)), the preconfigured value of 512 is simply a "sane default".